# FormEditText not clearing after correct input

Tags: android

I use the [FormEditText](https://github.com/vekexasia/android-form-edittext/) widget for a form (obviously). Thing is: After being tested not valid once, the warning red exclamation mark won't disappear even after entering a correct input and the `field.testValidity()` returning true. I also haven't found a method of `FormEditText` to manually clear it. 
Anyone else experienced this?

This is the method I use when the send button is tapped from the action bar:

```
public boolean checkFields() {

    FormEditText[] allFields = { firstname, lastname, street, zip, city,
            email, phone };

    boolean allValid = true;
    FormEditText firstFailedField = null;
    for (FormEditText field : allFields) {
        if (!field.testValidity()) {

            Log.d("FOR", "failed field: " + field.getHint());

            allValid = false;

            if (firstFailedField == null) {
                firstFailedField = field;
            }
        }

    }

    if (allValid) {

    } else {
        firstFailedField.requestFocus();
    }

    return allValid;

}
```

And this is part of my layout:

```
   <com.andreabaccega.widget.FormEditText
            android:id="@+id/firstname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Vorname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true"
            whatever:customRegexp="[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
            whatever:emptyErrorString="Bitte Vornamen angeben"
            whatever:testErrorString="Bitte Vornamen angeben"
            whatever:testType="regexp" >
        </com.andreabaccega.widget.FormEditText>

        <com.andreabaccega.widget.FormEditText
            android:id="@+id/lastname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Nachname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true"
            whatever:customRegexp="[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
            whatever:emptyErrorString="Bitte Nachnamen angeben"
            whatever:testErrorString="Bitte Nachnamen angeben"
            whatever:testType="regexp" >
        </com.andreabaccega.widget.FormEditText>
```

I entered Kim in the firstname field, pressed send. Theres a warning on the lastname field. Enter Jong in the lastname field, but the exclamation mark won't hide. And the field does test valid!

[image]

Comment: You can try field.setError(null): in this way you can hide the error from an EditText. It should work for FormEditText since FormEditText extends EditText

Comment: @UngureanuLiviu [I was just going through the source code](https://github.com/vekexasia/android-form-edittext/blob/master/library/src/com/andreabaccega/widget/DefaultEditTextValidator.java#L111) and wanted to say the same right now. But it seems like you were faster. You should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As suggested I'll post my comment as an answer:*

You can try field.setError(null): in this way you can hide the error from an EditText. It should work for FormEditText since FormEditText extends EditText.